# I2C read() lost 1 bit

Tags: i2c, c

I try to use I2C to read data from ADS1110, the address of ADS1110 is seven bits, which is `1001 000`. Writing data can only change the configuration register, which is done in the form of address + configuration. Reading data returns 3 bytes of data, which are high-order bytes data, low-order bytes data, and configuration. The default configuration of ADS1110 is 0x8C, and the highest bit is generally 0 in continuous mode, indicating that the converted data is the latest. I use read() and write() to implement I2C reading, the code is as follows:

```c
#define NUMS 10
char readbuf[NUMS];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // int file = i2c_init("/dev/i2c-0", 0x48);
    int file = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);

    int addr = 0b01001000;

    if (file < 0)
    {
        printf("openfile error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0)
    {
        printf("ioctl error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Debug Gain 1
    readbuf[0] = 0x0C;

    if (write(file, readbuf, 1) != 1)
    {
        printf("write error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (read(file, readbuf, 3) != 3)
    {
        printf("read error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%x %x %x\n", readbuf[0] & 0xff, readbuf[1] & 0xff, readbuf[2] & 0xff);

    close(file);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here I configure the ADS1110 as 0x0C, which means that I am reading in continuous mode, and the gain of the ADC is 1 times, and the specified reading rate is 15sps, that is, I can read 2.048V (7FFF) with 16-bit accuracy enter. But when my input is less than 1.024V, the read result is correct; when the data is greater than 1.024V, `D14` should be 1, but I get a result of 0. For example, when the input is 1.5V, the output should is `5D XX (0101)`, but I only get `1D XX (0001)`. But except for D14, the values ​​of all registers including Config are correct. The result displayed by the oscilloscope is shown in the following figure:

[image: pic1]

The bus only has one device, which is ADS1110:

```shell
# i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: There is a very small green glitch at the end of the bad bit. Looks like a 1 is clamped down by something and the clamp is released with the falling edge of CLK. There is no other glitch like this. I have no explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an NS2009 on the board, and the address conflicts with the ADS1110.